# copying multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two function say responseA(); and responseB(); which returns a 2d and 3d array respectively.
I am trying to copy (1st and 2nd) column of $responseA and (2nd and 3rd) column of $responseB to a new 3d array called $response, the third column in the new array would be 'A' or 'B' depending upon where it came from. Example:

```
$responseA = responseA(); $responseB = responseB(); 

$responseA[1,1371500801]; $responseB[111,1,1371340804];
$responseA[2,1371504502]; $responseB[131,2,1371760805];
$responseA[3,1371534503]; $responseB[121,3,1371130806];
```

the final array :

```
   $response[1,1371500801,A];
    $response[2,1371504502,A];
    $response[3,1371534503,A];
    $response[1,1371340804,B];
    $response[2,1371760805,B];
    $response[3,1371130806,B];
```

This is what I have done till now

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($responseA);$i++){
            $response0[$i][0] = $myComments[$i][0];
            $response0[$i][1] = $myComments[$i][1];
            $response0[$i][2] = 'A';
        }
        for ($i=0;$i<count($responseB[0]);$i++){
            $response1[$i][0] = $responseB[1][$i];
            $response1[$i][1] = $responseB[2][$i];
                        $response1[$i][2] = 'B';
        }
$response = array_merge($response0,$response1);
```

Could anyone here help me code the correct solution to create the response array and sort this array according to the 2nd column (which is a time-stamp)

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you looked at array_unique()? Coupled together with array_merge() they could make this a bit easier I think.

Comment: OK, I will add it. Any other suggestion to make this process efficient.